# Was a registry of Muslims maintained in past?

Tags: practical-islam, history, khilafah

It is required in Islam to pay the zakat and other obligations towards the leader of the Muslims, for this a registry of Muslims is essential was such a registry maintained by the Muslims of the time? and does it help to have a global database of Muslims around the world for better management and utilization of Muslim resources?

**Motivation:**

There is a major Shia Islamic sect which makes it compulsory to have a unique ID cards for its adherents and I see them using it to profile its adherents and manage the human resources in an efficient way. All their religious activities, payments etc are logged in a global database. Is this a correct thing to do?

Answer (score -4):

That would be against the basic principle of Islam-- no one else could tell what one believes in. Even zakat-- which has a society aspect is totally voluntary, on one's own judgement. I don't think anyone should be asked to "declare" his/her religion. It should remain between the self and the God.

Comment: Ofcourse we judge by what is visible and this applied to all who call themselves Muslims and not those who wont.

Comment: There can be and not hard to gather has been those pretending to believe. Zakat is one way. You can judge giving away to others. what for he did is not upon you.

Comment: Zakat is not my motivation behind the question nor is personal relationship with God, I am just exploring the efficiency of a Database that can help the Muslims

Comment: Your db wouldn't necessarily be accurate. Not all muslims would be willing to talk about their beliefs. I personally dislike the idea-- a step to categorizing people on their beliefs wouldn`t be any different.